# How to combine disks from XEN-hosts into one storage?

Tags: xen, vsan

We have 4 servers with XenServer 7.x installed. Each server has a large disk (6TB - raid10). How can I combine these disks in one big storage for sharing? This should be an analog of vSAN from VMware.

Answer (score 6):

There are some storage solutions that operate in a similar way as to VMware vSAN. The ones that got popularity in virtualization sphere are:

[Dell EMC Unity](https://www.emc.com/products-solutions/trial-software-download/unity-vsa.htm): I doubt they support Xen though.

[HPE StoreVirtual VSA](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/storage/storevirtual.html): The same concerns here.

[StarWind vSAN](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free): I almost sure they do support Xen.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you.
In phone conversation with StarWind's manager he told me what SW vSAN works only on Windows-platform. 

In fact we need something like  "plugin / extension" for Xen, what allow to combine and to use all local disks as one big shared SR for Xen

Comment: They have a free Linux VSA, however, I haven't yet tried it. Also, you can install it inside a Windows VM and it will work just fine.